# Output macro execution steps

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to visualize the macro execution steps, in real time?
Ex.

```
Sub activate_sheets()
Worksheets("s1").Activate
'some code
Worksheets("s2").Activate
'some code
........    
End Sub
```

I want to see during the execution if s1 was processed, then if s2 was processed etc.

like this
codeline1 - processed
codeline2 - processed
...
in other words, some 'immediate window', but not in vba mode
thank you

Comment: Yes, you can set break points after lines you'd like to check. Once the code reaches the brak point, it will stop and by hovering over the variables etc., you can check their state.
It's also useful to enable Locals And Immediate windows in VBA editor. The first one lists all variables for the current module an their state and the other one can be used to insert a piece of code or temporarily print something, using `Debug.Print`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Debug.Print("") to write log in debug window.

```
Sub activate_sheets()
  Worksheets("s1").Activate
    'some code
    debug.print ("worksheet S1 processed")
  Worksheets("s2").Activate
    'some code
    debug.print ("worksheet S2 processed")
  End Sub
```

However, that is only if you are executing the macro from Visual Basic Editor. If you wish to make an user able to see what steps were processed, than you may want to display a custom form and create some some type of progress bar. It is what I use mostly - users like to see progress bars.

Please find sample file at http://www.filedropper.com/progressbartest  - I built it in a rush. But it will give you an idea at least ...

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to bring up your VBA editor, click inside the code and press F8. Each time you press F8 it steps through the code one line. To see the results on the sheet, switch over to the sheet and look. To see your variable values, just hover your mouse over them in the code and the current values will popup in an intellisense window. You can even see the current value by using `Immediate Window` by typing `?` followed by the variable or the properties of objects.

Alternatively, you can use `Debug.Print` statement after each line.